# define by $l(n)$ number of different prime numbers dividing n, is sequence $a{n} = l(n^2 + 1)$ bounded?

Tags: number-theory

define by $l(n)$ number of different prime numbers dividing n, is sequence $a{n} = l(n^2 + 1)$ bounded?

This is what I've tried:
let $S$ be a set containing all prime numbers dividing $n^2 + 1$ for some $n$, and M product of all elements in S, then i tried to construct another number by $(M+1)^2n^2 + 1$, now if we define $S'$ as set of all prime numbers dividing $(M+1)^2n^2 + 1$ we notice that $|S'| \geq |S|$ and tried to prove that eventually $|S'| > |S|$ but to no avail, any help?
(The starting $n$ will be $5$, and $S={2, 5}$)

Comment: Hint: if $p$ is a prime number dividing $n^2+1$, then $p$ also divides $(n+kp)^2+1$ for any integer $k$. Use this with lots of different primes to find an $m$ such that all those primes simultaneously divide $m^2+1$.

Comment: Use Chinese remainder theorem to show if $m_1\mid n_1^2+1, m_2\mid n_2^2+1,$ with $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$ then there is an $n$ with $m_1m_2\mid n^2+1.$ Then show there are infinitely many primes for which this is true.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to prove a much more general result.

Let $P(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients. By [Schur's lemma for integer polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem), there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p|P(a)$ for some integer $a$.

We will show that for every $k \geq 1$ there is some positive integer $a$ such that $P(a)$ has at least $k$ different prime divisors. Indeed, let $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ be different prime numbers and let $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ be integers such that $p_i | P(a_i)$. Such prime numbers exist because of Schur's lemma.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that there exists some positive integer $a$ such that $a \equiv a_i \pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,...,k$. Then we also have $P(a) \equiv P(a_i) \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,k$, so $P(a)$ has at least $k$ different prime divisors.